# How to get Ubuntu clients to use newer SMB protocol with cifs-utils?

Tags: samba

How do I make my Ubuntu client machines connect to my samba server with protocol > SMB1, for shares mounted through fstab with cifs-utils?

This shows a sample redacted output from smbstatus.

The machine connecting from XXX.YYY.ZZZ.9 is a Windows 7 machine and is connected with SMB2_10 protocol.

The machine connecting from  XXX.YYY.ZZZ.5 is an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and is connected with SMB1 protocol.

This tells me that *it isn't the server that is driving the protocol level*, since the Windows machine connects with the better protocol.

How do I force the Ubuntu machines to use the better protocol?

```
PID     Username      Group         Machine            Protocol Version       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9683      me          me          XXX.YYY.ZZZ.9  (ipv4:XXX.YYY.ZZZ.9:49158) SMB2_10     
1935      me          me          XXX.YYY.ZZZ.5  (ipv4:XXX.YYY.ZZZ.5:55020) NT1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding another option to your fstab statement for that share:

```
vers=3.0
```

That will force the connection to use SMB 3.0 instead of the default.

A modern samba server is set to go up to SMBv3.

Comment: This worked perfectly.